# Query giving different result sets

Tags: java, orm, mybatis

I am facing a weird issue in which I am getting different result set when I am running a query in psql service platform and when mapping a corresponding map in mybatis.

```
@Select("SELECT x.a AS \"xyz.a\", x.b AS \"xyz.b\", y.something AS \"def.something\" FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.someproperty = y.someotherproperty")
@MapKey("xyz")
Map<xyz, def> getProperties();
```

Now at first look it was fetching me 5 tupples instead of 9(which was on psql service platform -- the correct ans) but still giving me modCount and count of the map to be 9. I figured out this has to do something with hashCode. After overriding the hashCode using the primary key id in both classes xyz and def it increased to 7 tupples. Now I am wondering why is it happening even though I am providing a primary key and using a prime distribution on the map. I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When you use @MapKey MyBatis first converts rows to list of objects of type of the value of the resulting `Map` (in your case of type `def`) and then takes value of property specified by `@MapKey` as a key (in your case of type `xyz`). This implies that `xyz` class should follow contract for `Map` keys that is it should define `hashCode` and `equals` which are [consistent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29). So the first thing you should take case are correct definition of these two methods.

Even if you have correct `hashCode` and `equals` defined you stil may see difference in number of rows if some of the rows returned by query has the same value with respect to you definition of equality for `xyz`.

For example if `xyz` is simple `String` the following result cannot be mapped correctly:

```
xyz | def
----+----
 ab |  1
 ab |  2
```

If you think for a minute you'll see that in this case there is no correct way to return results as a `Map`. This can be done correctly only if keys are unique in the resultset.